# Test Rest API with file_get_contents

Tags: rest, api, file-get-contents

I am having issues testing a rest API. I want to trigger it from PHP by doing a file_get_contents.

This is my code so far

```
<?php
$url = 'http://domain:0000/rest/createUser?u=username&p=password&username=testuser&password=testpassword&email=user@domain.co.uk&';
$encodedUrl = urlencode($url);
$apicall = file_get_contents($url);
?>
```

This URL works from a browser, but as soon as I use file_get_contents it doesn't work.

Could the end server be blocking the use of file_get_contents? If so how? and how can I begin to test and troubleshoot this?

Comment: You shouldn't be encoding the url before you call `file_get_contents` on it.  You also should be using PHP curl_* functions instead to make a request.

Comment: i tired with Curl but I had the same issues too

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're using urlencode.

The `urlencode` function is used specifically for encoding strings inside a portion of a url. For example, you can use it to add data after the `?`, and make sure that things like `&` turns into `%26` and spaces turn into `%20`.

But it's not used to encode the entire url, it just makes the url invalid.

Comment: thanks @Evert, but if I don't use URL encode is it not invalid as use file_get_contents("urlgoeshere") ?

Comment: http://domain:0000/rest/createUser?u=username&p=password&username=testuser&password=testpassword&email=user@domain.co.uk

is this not a valid URL ? tested using this and it doesn't work, but the URL works from a browser

Comment: That does not look like a valid url to me. It's at least missing a scheme, and a port can not be 0. Also generally, if something 'doesn't work' you should share what happens instead. You're probably getting an error

Comment: I modified the URL and port for security purposes...

http://www.subsonic.org/pages/api.jsp

This is the API docs for my home media server

Comment: I am confident in the URL as it works in a browser, just not when placed into $payload = file_get_contents("http://urlgoes.here:000"); I tried turning error reporting on but I only get a blank screen

Comment: Browsers are a bit more relaxed with urls, because they need to deal a bit better with users mistyping urls. The format for the url in your last comment is still invalid for the same reasons as the last. It's missing the scheme and it's an invalid port number.

Comment: Sorry the url I am actually using for clarity is
`http://mydomain.org.uk:8080/rest/createUser?u=username&p=password&username=testuser&password=testpassword&email=user@domain.co.uk&`

Comment: That port is better, but you're still missing the scheme! it's `http://` or `https://`

Comment: sorry see above... stackexchange removes URL schemes from URLs unless you use ` characters

Comment: ok just saw your update, that is a valid url. If that doesn't work, I would look in 2 areas: 1) Maybe a different part of your code is doing something wrong, or 2) get error mesaging turned on

Comment: If you're getting literally nothing back in your browser, you should try to troubleshoot why your error messages are not being displayed. You can also check your server logs potentially

Comment: error messages are turned on, php mysql errors display. Turned on in my ini.php file and also error_reporting is on for E_ALL and ~E_NOTICE

Comment: is allow_url_fopen on?

Comment: yes @danronmoon it's working with another php file on the same URL to another API elsewhere too

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the last "&" in your URL and then use the $encodedUrl instead of $url in the file get contents.

So try to turn this :

```
$apicall = file_get_contents($url);
```

INTO

```
$apicall = file_get_contents($encodedUrl);
```